# How can i detect that publisher is disconnected with ZeroMQ and Node.js

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I am using Node.js + ZeroMQ for subscribing to a certain feed using the PUB/SUB pattern.
How could i detect the condition where my publisher is disconnected? (I am connected as a subscriber)

Another thing: is there a way to get automatically messages from the past when i first connected to the publisher?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could publish a heartbeat and if your subscriber misses one or more in-a-row you can assume that you lost the connection and try to reconnect.

To get the messages from the past you need to use a different pattern, like REQuesting those missing messages. In this case you need a way to identify which messages are missing.

Answer (score 1):

In ZeroMQ's default pubsub model, there's no way for the subscriber to get messages from the past. See the [ZeroMQ documentation](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall), where you find statements like

> If you start the SUB socket (i.e., establish a connection to a PUB
>   socket) after the PUB socket has started sending out data, you will
>   lose whatever it published before the connection was made. If this is
>   a problem, set up your architecture so the SUB socket starts first,
>   then the PUB socket starts publishing.

and

> Pub-sub is like a radio broadcast; you miss everything before you
>   join, and then how much information you get depends on the quality of
>   your reception.